# Place Auto-complete implementation

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, google-maps-android-api-2

I've got this code for one of my activities that is supposed to give the option to autocomplete with an address as the user starts typing, but it crashes when trying to start the activity.

```
package com.reachmenow;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class JoinMeNow extends Activity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyAZQpyuuupl4aRHAzfxkaV4jlAmM9nRwxA";

    ListView listView1, listView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_now);

        String[] contacts = { "ex1", "ex2" };
        String[] recent = { "first", "second" };


        TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tab_host);
        th.setup();

        // tab1
        TabSpec recentLocationsTab = th.newTabSpec("tab1");
        recentLocationsTab.setContent(R.id.recent_locations_tab);
        recentLocationsTab.setIndicator("Recent");
        th.addTab(recentLocationsTab);

        // tab2
        TabSpec allFriendsTab = th.newTabSpec("tab2");
        allFriendsTab.setContent(R.id.all_friends_tab);
        allFriendsTab.setIndicator("All Friends");
        th.addTab(allFriendsTab);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                contacts);

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                recent);
        listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter autoComplete = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item);
        int q = autoComplete.getCount();
        System.out.print(q);
    }

    //Autocomplte method
    private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&components=country:uk");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }
    private class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList<String> resultList;

        public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }};
            return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

the activity is declared on the manifest.

This are the exceptions on the the logCat:

```
    08-31 23:27:54.012: W/dalvikvm(10853): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414ea2a0)
08-31 23:27:54.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10853): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 23:27:54.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10853): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.reachmenow/com.reachmenow.JoinMeNow}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 23:27:54.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10853): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: post the entire error

Comment: I had posted the wrong one, I guess this is what you are looking for since it would be imposible to post the entire logcat in here

Comment: So you get a NullPointerException ... have you tried to find out why and where you getting it? Have you tried to fix it?

Comment: yes, i have been looking for it but I cant find it. The only place I can think of is: ArrayList<String> resultList = null; that is setting the ArrayList to null and then returning it and that value is used after. but I tried trowing an exception for NullPiontException under the tag ExampleApp but it didnt throw it so i'm guessing is not that variable

Comment: You may should look at the line of code where the NullPointerException occurs. The Stacktrace should tell you that. Like `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.my.package.MyClass.myMethod(MyClass.java:lineNumber)`. Also you should never use null as a "valid" value. If an error occurs and you would like to return null as a result, then forward the exception instead and handle with that in the calling method.

Comment: You could try to post the last `Caused by` part of your Stacktrace in your Question. That shouldn't be too long and it may helps us to help you.

Comment: sorry I dont see anything else besides what I already posted for the line :  Caused by.... it just ends there, in NullPointerException

Comment: Then you should debug the program to find the exact spot.